# vscode error about "--inspect-brk" when I run yarn test every time via vscode debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs, yarnpkg

I want to debug my unit test in vsCode, it was ruined by yarn:

`yarn test path`

my vsCode configuration:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "yarn test",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "test",
      ],
      "args": ["src/apps/trips/components/ChangePayoutModal/__test__/ChangePayoutModal.spec.js"],
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
```

but I got error:

```
$ node scripts/test.js --inspect-brk=31516 src/apps/trips/components/ChangePayoutModal/__test__/ChangePayoutModal.spec.js
● Unrecognized CLI Parameters:

  Following options were not recognized:
  ["inspect-brk", "inspectBrk"]

  CLI Options Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html
```

vsCode add `inspect-brk` option and don't recognize it? how should I do

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran into more problems after this issue, I'm guessing. I'm still working on this task myself. That said, here's the answer to your question. [I found it here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21620) If you add  a port to your configuration, at least that problem will go away.

```
      "port": 4079 (for example)
```

Comment: I did get through my issues earlier today, so if you're interested, I could write them up.